# Unable to use drawable in EditText inside TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-design-library, android-textinputlayout

I recently upgraded Android Design library from 24.2.1 to 25.0.0. 
After this the "drawableX" feature in EditText doesn't work.

EDIT 01.11:
I learned that setting drawable in xml works if you use android:drawableStart instead of android:drawableLeft. But setting setting drawables programatically does not work. I use this to make a "Clear"-button to empty the EditText. But this feature is broken now. I would appreciate any work-arounds or knowledge about if this is intentional from Google or a bug!

My code for Clearable edit-text that worked before but doesn't now:

```
public class ClearableErrorTextInputEditText extends ErrorTextInputEditText implements View.OnFocusChangeListener, View.OnTouchListener, TextWatcher {

private Drawable resIcon;
private OnFocusChangeListener childFocusListener;

public ClearableErrorTextInputEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setup();
}

public ClearableErrorTextInputEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setup();
}

public ClearableErrorTextInputEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setup();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (getCompoundDrawables()[2] != null) {
            final boolean tappedClose = event.getX() > (getWidth() - getPaddingRight() - resIcon.getIntrinsicWidth());
            if (tappedClose) {
                setText("");
                return false; // true will fail on emulator running 2.1 and physical keyboard / scroll wheel
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void setOnFocusChangeListener(OnFocusChangeListener l) {
    childFocusListener = l;
}

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    setClearIconVisible(hasFocus && getText().length() > 0);

    if (childFocusListener!=null){
        childFocusListener.onFocusChange(v, hasFocus);
    }
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
    super.onTextChanged(s, start, before, count);
    setClearIconVisible(isFocused() && s.length() > 0);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {} // not interesting

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {} //  // not interesting

private void setup() {
    if(isInEditMode()){
        return;
    }

    resIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_clear, null);
    resIcon.setBounds(0, 0, resIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), resIcon.getIntrinsicHeight());

    setClearIconVisible(false);

    super.setOnTouchListener(this);
    super.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    addTextChangedListener(this);
}

private void setClearIconVisible(final boolean visible){
    final Drawable icon = visible ? resIcon : null;
    setCompoundDrawables(getCompoundDrawables()[0],
            getCompoundDrawables()[1], icon, getCompoundDrawables()[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer by Ahmed Ashraf G, I was able to find the solution.
Changing the following code:

```
setCompoundDrawables(getCompoundDrawables()[0],
        getCompoundDrawables()[1], icon, getCompoundDrawables()[3]);
```

to:

```
setCompoundDrawablesRelative(getCompoundDrawablesRelative()[0],
            getCompoundDrawablesRelative()[1], icon, getCompoundDrawablesRelative()[3]);
```

From other places on StackOverflow (the documentation does NOT mention this) the difference between xxxCompoundDrawablesXxx and xxxCompundDrawablesRelativeXxx is that the relative versions take into account RTL-languages, ie they are the same as using drawableStart instead of drawableLeft.

So in conclusion, Google has broken all methods that are not RTL-methods for EditText inside TextInputLayout. Since the new methods are added in API level 17 I see this as major bug, that will probably be fixed in future updates

Comment: I know it's a long time, but there's a way to set a two drawables at the end of edit text?

Answer (score 28):

This is the easiest way I could find:

Step 1.

On your layout, set your ***endIconDrawable***, It's important to know that it will not show if you don't set the ***endIconMode***.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/custom_end_icon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_text"
    app:endIconMode="custom"
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/custom_icon"
    app:endIconContentDescription="@string/custom_content_desc">

  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Step 2. Depending on what you want to do with the button, these are the three methods you can call on it

```
TextInputLayout textInputCustomEndIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.custom_end_icon);

// If the icon should work as button, set an OnClickListener to it.
textInputCustomEndIcon
    .setEndIconOnClickListener(/* custom OnClickListener */);

// If any specific changes should be done when the EditText is attached (and
// thus when the end icon is added to it), set an OnEditTextAttachedListener
textInputCustomEndIcon
    .addOnEditTextAttachedListener(/* custom OnEditTextAttachedListener */);

// If any specific changes should be done if/when the endIconMode gets changed,
// set an OnEndIconChangedListener
textInputCustomEndIcon
    .addOnEndIconChangedListener(/* custom OnEndIconChangedListener */);
```

For more on Customization, and additional features check this [Link](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/) cheers

Comment: Up vote for your "It's important to know that it will not show if you don't set the endIconMode." sentence.

Comment: Great answer! works perfectly

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same issue, All I did was add `drawableStart` along with `drawableLeft` and it's shown as expected.

Comment: Yup, it's weird though, drawableLeft shouldn't be dependent of drawableStart, probably a bug.

Comment: But my real problem is that I want to do it programatically, as I show and hide the clear-icon if there is text or not. I use setCompoundDrawables(), and this shows nothing (it did before)

Comment: Changed the question to reflect my real problem

Comment: aha this looks interesting, I'm gonna investigate on it further as I haven't tried to change it programmatically before

Comment: I found the "solution" based on your answer. Posted it in another answer

Comment: Left side working fine but same case not working for Right side , I added drawableRight with drawableEnd but icon still not showing

Answer (score 3):

Add endIconMode to Custom for adding drawable end for a textinputlayout.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
   app:endIconMode="custom"
   app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_tick_grey"
   ....
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing EditText by android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText, for example:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     android:id="@+id/email_input"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
          android:id="@+id/email"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:hint="@string/email_hint"
          android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_clear" />
 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: This gives the following error: Element TextInputEditText is not allowed here. Also in xml the solution given by Ahmed Ashraf works (use drawableStart).