# Method setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds doesn't work when EditText wrapped in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-support-library, androiddesignsupport, android-textinputlayout

I guess I found some wrong behaviour in last `com.android.support:design` library(v25.0.0).

Method `EditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` doesn't work when `EditText` wrapped in `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`.

Is there workaround for that (I don't want to rollback library or change my layout)?

Comment: Use "relative" version of that method

Comment: ...which is `setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds()`.

Comment: Really thanks, I did not notice this method

Comment: [Here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361107/unable-to-use-drawable-in-edittext-inside-textinputlayout). Finally found it. They broke something with the latest update, apparently.